# Passing data having a line break in angular JS

Tags: javascript, c, angularjs, http-post

I'm having this code for passing of data..

```
    var variable1 =""; 
variable1 += "Hi \n how are you"; 
var variable2 = ""; 
variable2 += "I'm fine";

$http.post('/someurl',{ variable1 : variable1,  variable2 :variable2}).success(function(data){
     viewAll.widget = data;
    });
```

The data should be received as \n.. I'm having a problem because its only receiving it as Hinhow are you
Thanks to  those would be able to help

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on where you want to display this data. In a JS alert it should show up fine.

However if you want to display this data in HTML you need to use `<br/>` instead of `/n` as `line break`.

```
viewAll.widget = data.replace('/n', '<br/>');
```

If you need to pass data back from the widget just do the replace the other way around.

Comment: Well that kinda solves my problem in showing the data in the front end.. but i need the "\n" to function for my back-end of the program..  But I'm gonna try this.. Thanks.

Comment: If you need to pass data back from the widget just replace `<br/>` with `/n`.